# How to place every child node from a specific parent node into its own parent node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, parent-child

I have a question.

I have the following XML input:

```
<root>
 <name>Dennis</name>
 <lastname>Some Lastname</lastname>
 <age>28</age>
   <hobbys>
      <hobby>test1</hobby>
      <hobby>test2</hobbyy>
      <hobby>test3</hobby>
   </hobbys>
 <food>pizza</food>
 <name>Bob</name>
 <lastname>Some Lastname</lastname>
 <age>48</age>
   <hobbys>
      <hobby>test4</hobby>
      <hobby>test5</hobbyy>
      <hobby>test6</hobby>
      <hobby>test7</hobby>
      <hobby>test8</hobby>
   </hobbys>
 <food>fries</food>
 <footerText>blablabla</footerText>
</root>
```

And would like to place every child node of a specific node into its own parent node (in this case I want to have a  parent node for all  child nodes, so the desired output will be:

```
<root>
 <name>Dennis</name>
 <lastname>Some Lastname</lastname>
 <age>28</age>
     <hobbys>
        <hobby>test1</hobby>
     </hobbys>
     <hobbys>
        <hobby>test2</hobby>
     </hobbys>
     <hobbys>
        <hobby>test3</hobby>
     </hobbys>
 <food>pizza</food>
 <name>Bob</name>
 <lastname>Some Lastname</lastname>
 <age>48</age>
   <hobbys>
      <hobby>test4</hobby>
   </hobbys>
   <hobbys>
      <hobby>test5</hobby>
   </hobbys>
   <hobbys>
      <hobby>test6</hobby>
   </hobbys>
   <hobbys>
      <hobby>test7</hobby>
   </hobbys>
   <hobbys>
      <hobby>test8</hobby>
   </hobbys>
 <food>fries</food>
 <footerText>blablabla</footerText>
</root>
```

What is the easiest way to get the desired result?
I have tried the following:

```
var xmlStr = [XML STRING];

xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);

xmlDoc.FirstChild.InnerXml = string.Join("", 
    xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//hobby")
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Select(n => n.OuterXml));

XmlElement elem;
foreach (XmlElement node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//root//hobby"))
{
    xmlDoc.FirstChild.RemoveChild(node);
    elem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hobbys");
    elem.AppendChild(node);
    xmlDoc.FirstChild.AppendChild(elem);
}
```

This however only works if there is one list of hobbys, and it will not remember the place where it comes from.. I'm kinda stuck so I would be very thankfull if someone could help me out!

Greetings!

Comment: Well, seems that your desired output is a step backward from the proper structure.
You should place each set of personal data (from <name> ... </food>) into separate element, for example `<person>` and leave the `<hoobys>` as they were in the first sample.

Comment: Hey, I want to use the desired output in my own application, and when I load the XML, it will not work with the current output. Placing the child nodes within their own parent node is a way to fix my issue, the question is how to do it :)

Comment: Well, you should probably be able to do it by using insert instead of append (like `InsertAfter`).

Comment: Tried, but I feel like something in general is wrong with the way I approach the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this is an interesting use of xml(one of the most important advantages of xml is to having proper parent/child presentation of data) but you can solve it like this:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(currentXML);
        foreach (var currHobbysNode in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//hobbys").Cast<XmlNode>())
        {
            foreach (var currHobbyNode in currHobbysNode.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>())
            {
                //Create a new node.
                var newHobbysElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hobbys");
                var newHobbyElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hobby");
                newHobbyElement.InnerText = currHobbyNode.InnerText;
                newHobbysElement.AppendChild(newHobbyElement);
                currHobbysNode.ParentNode.InsertBefore(newHobbysElement, currHobbysNode);
            }
            currHobbysNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(currHobbysNode);
        }
```

it seems obvious but what's happening here is we loop for every 'hobbys' node and get the childs, and then create new 'hobbys' node for each 'hobby' child. here is a sample fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/GSd86D